# Store procedure for retrieving data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have some five tables which look like this

```
BugHistory             
--------------------   
BugHistoryID
BugId
EmployeeId                  

Bugs
--------------------
BugID
Description
ProjectID
PriorityID

Employee                    
-------------------      
EmployeeId
EmployeeName   

Projects                
-------------------     
ProjectID
ProjectName    

Priority
-------------------
PriorityID
PriorityName
```

I want to retrieve data from all of the tables, making `BugHistory` the main table.

I need `[Description],[ProjectName],[PriorityName]` from all the remaining four tables where `EmployeeID` is the key.

The data should be retrieved based on EmployeeID from BugHistory table; I will be getting the EmployeeID based on login.  Can any one help me in writing this query?

Comment: What does your query look like?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

This should get you what you need.

```
SELECT b.Description
    , pj.ProjectName
    , pr.PriorityName
FROM BugHistory bh
INNER JOIN Employee e
     ON bh.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN Bugs b
     ON bh.BugId = b.BugId
INNER JOIN Project pj
    ON b.ProjectId = pj.ProjectId
INNER JOIN Priority pr
    ON b.PriorityId = pr.PriorityId
```